# XAML markup error in visual studio-design window

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, material-design

I am new in WPF application design. I have created a window using visual studio IDE.  But I got an error in design window when am trying to add material design in my XAML code. But i can run the window without any error. This is my screen
[image]

Due to this issue, I cant design my application. How to solve this XAML markup issue. Any idea?

Comment: I can run the code but only the issue with designer. any one please help me

Comment: What is the error the editor prompts? Try to run the following command: `taskkill /im xdesproc.exe /f`, this kills all xaml designer processes, then you will be asked to reload the designer. This has helped me sometimes

Comment: this is the error : the name "Hint Assist" does not exist in the namespace "http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"